# Trying to reload what's inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I have this.fetchStock("aapl") inside componentDidMount which works very good, but now i want to run fetchStock() again when pressing a button for example, but this time with a different input (another stock name), for example: this.fetchStock("AMZN").

Can someone give me a direction for it ? I've tried to call this.fetchStock("AMZN") inside button onclick but it doesn't work.

Thanks !

```
import React from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';


class Stock extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stockChartXValues: [],
        stockChartYValues: [],
    }


}


componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStock("aapl");
}

fetchStock(s) {

    const pointerToThis = this;
    //console.log(pointerToThis);
    let StockSymbol = s;
    const API_KEY = 'AUVHHUK64JIJCXOP';

    let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${StockSymbol}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${API_KEY}`;

    let stockChartXValuesFunction = [];
    let stockChartYValuesFunction = [];



    fetch(API_Call)

        // Response & Data are just names (variables)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                // Key is the Date
                for (var key in data['Time Series (Daily)']) {
                    stockChartXValuesFunction.push(key)
                    stockChartYValuesFunction.push(data['Time Series (Daily)'][key]['4. close']);
                }
                // console.log(stockChartXValuesFunction);

                pointerToThis.setState({
                    stockChartXValues: stockChartXValuesFunction,
                    stockChartYValues: stockChartYValuesFunction
                });
            }
        )
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Stock Market</h1>
            <Plot
                data={[
                    {
                        x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
                        y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
                        type: 'scatter',
                        mode: 'lines+markers',
                        marker: { color: 'red' },
                    }
                ]}
                layout={{ width: 720, height: 440, title: "myTitle" }}
            />
            <button onClick={this.fetchStock("AMZN")}>Click me!</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}




  export default Stock;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a callback function to `onClick`:

```js
<button onClick={() => this.fetchStock("AMZN")}>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to understand why callback is needed... Is it because we want fetchstock() to run only after the button is clicked ?

Comment: @YuvalShamir Yes, because when you pass it without callback, you are calling the function and actually passing the function's return value.